# ChartJS "half donut" chart not displaying properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js

My chart is not displaying properly, here is how it displays and how it is suppose to display:

How it displays:

[image]

How it is suppose to look like:

[image]

My html code:

```
<div style="display:block; width: 400px; height: 400px">
    <canvas id="dashboardChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

My typescript component code:

```
var data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30]
      }],
      labels: [
        'Red',
        'Yellow',
        'Blue'
      ]
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("dashboardChart") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: {
        rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
        circumference: 1 * Math.PI
      }
    });
```

If anyone can assist, it would get greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Doughnut rotation option is now in degrees

Try these changes:

```
circumference: 180,
rotation: -90,
```

Migration [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Comment: You are a hero, robert.