# How to display half chart.js donut graph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js, donut-chart

In my project, I have a doughnut graph. But I want it to look like a speedometer. I created the donut graph using chart.js (HTML, CSS, js). I merely want to show it halfway or as a speedometer. Here is the sample of what I want it to display like

[image]

```js
// Data for the donut chart (Group 2 first, then Group 1)
const data = {
    labels: ['Group 2', 'Group 1'], // Swap the order of labels
    datasets: [{
        data: [30, 70], // Swap the order of data values
        backgroundColor: ['#A1A5B7', '#F1BC00'], // Colors for each group
    }]
};

// Configuration for the chart
const config = {
    type: 'doughnut', // Use doughnut chart type for a donut chart
    data: data,
    options: {
        rotation: 0.5 * Math.PI, // Rotate the chart to 180 degrees
        cutout: '70%', // Cutout percentage for a 180-degree chart
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false, // Hide the legend if not needed
            },
        },
    },
};

// Get the canvas element and create the chart
const canvas = document.getElementById('donut-chart');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.donut-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.chart-container {
  width: 100%; /* Make the container responsive */
  max-width: 500px; /* Optionally, set a maximum width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="donut-container">
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="donut-chart"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990859/half-doughnut-chart-with-chart-js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512787/chartjs-half-donut-chart-not-displaying-properly
it has been asked before. Did you have a look at those answers?

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question.

Answer (score 4):

I removed your `rotation: 0.5 * Math.PI` and added this instead

```
rotation: -90, 
circumference: 180,
```

```js
// Data for the donut chart (Group 2 first, then Group 1)
const data = {
    labels: ['Group 2', 'Group 1'], // Swap the order of labels
    datasets: [{
        data: [30, 70], // Swap the order of data values
        backgroundColor: ['#A1A5B7', '#F1BC00'], // Colors for each group
    }]
};

// Configuration for the chart
const config = {
    type: 'doughnut', // Use doughnut chart type for a donut chart
    data: data,
    options: {
        rotation: -90, 
        circumference: 180,
        cutout: '70%', // Cutout percentage for a 180-degree chart
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false, // Hide the legend if not needed
            },
        },
    },
};

// Get the canvas element and create the chart
const canvas = document.getElementById('donut-chart');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.donut-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.chart-container {
  width: 100%; /* Make the container responsive */
  max-width: 500px; /* Optionally, set a maximum width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="donut-container">
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="donut-chart"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But maybe they wanted Pie, Donuts and Coffee!  :)  Good post BTW.

Comment: `Math. = Math.PI;` and then you'll have to assign  `Math.`  and `Math.☕` to whatever makes the most sense!